# Not able to return a type that requires a cast (F#)

Tags: types, casting, f#

I am not able to return the specific case of a type to another type that just wants to hold the generic case, and not actually implement a specific example. (For example and not related to the types below, instead of returning 0.1 with units of centimeters, I am trying to return centimeters).

My type is defined as follows:

```
 type UnitOfMeasure =
    | Foo of decimal
    | Bar of decimal
    | Baz of decimal
```

I then also have:

```
 type BlahComponent =
    { Name : string
      Units : UnitOfMeasure }
```

I am given a string representation of the type of UnitOfMeasure, and I am trying to decide which UnitOfMeasure (Foo, Bar, or Baz) I have. I am using the following function:

```
let decideUnitOfMeasure stringRepresentationOfUnitOfMeasureType = 
    match stringRepresentationOfUnitOfMeasureType with 
      | "Foo" -> Foo
      | "Bar" -> Bar 
      | "Baz" -> Baz
```

Finally, I try to assign the return value of decideUnitOfMeasure to BlahComponent

```
        let stringRepresentationOfUnitOfMeasureType = "Foo"
        let bomComponent = {Name = "nameString"
                            Units = decideUnitOfMeasure stringRepresentationOfUnitOfMeasureType}
```

Trying to assign the return of decideUnitOfMeasure to Units results in the following error:
The expression was expected to have type 'UnitOfMeasure' but has type '(decimal -> UnitOfMeasure)'.

It appears that by the definition of UnitOfMeasure, returning the actual case of Foo, Bar, or Baz is not possible because it requires casting UnitOfMeasure to a decimal. Is there any way to return the actual case without casting to a decimal?

Answer (score 2):

You may be best served by redefining `UnitOfMeasure` to act more like a simple enumeration, where the constructors have no arguments:

```
type UnitOfMeasure =
    | Foo
    | Bar
    | Baz
```

Now you can move the decimal value so that it is not a type parameter. You could create a record type or even keep it as a simple tuple:

```
type BlahComponent =
    { Name : string
      Value : UnitOfMeasure * decimal }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not about casting. It is just a type error.

`Foo` is a constructor for the `UnitOfMeasure` type. It has the type `decimal -> UnitOfMeasure`. This means it takes a `decimal` value and returns a `UnitOfMeasure`.

So `Foo` on its own is not a UnitOfMeasure, but `Foo 1m` is. Your `Units` field actually stores the number as well, and you have not provided the number.

This explains why you are seeing this error. The answer from Chad Gilbert offers a possible alternative approach, but the best approach really depends on what you're trying to do.